# Modifying python's string Formatter

Tags: python, string

I have a function which takes no arguments and returns a string, which I want to be called using a string format. Here it is, and here's how I've tried to use [`format`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format):

```
def cabbages():
    return 'hello'

In [2]: '{cabbages} world'.format(**locals())
Out[2]: '<function cabbages at 0x101f75578> world'

In [3]: '{cabbages()} world'.format(**locals())
KeyError: 'cabbages()'
```

*So neither of which is quite what I want, i.e. the value of `cabbages()`.*

[PEP 3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) describes some way in which `string.Formatter` can be overwritten but it doesn't seem to give many examples. How can I subclass/customise the string [`Formatter`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter) class to do this?

*A hacky thing I considered would be to overwrite the `__getattr__` method of `cabbages`, and I **really** don't want be "considered pathological" (or, at least, *that* pathological).*

Comment: Using `str.format()` with `locals()` is generally a really bad idea. Just pass the values you want.

Comment: @Lattyware True, I actually use a different dictionary, was for example (a poor choice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the main deficiency I see in your answer is that it doesn't also handle the original compound field name syntaxes like `0.name` for 'getattr'/'dot' operator access nor, `0[name]` for 'getitem' retrieval specified in PEP 3101.

Here's a version that works in both Python 2.7 and 3.3. A major implementation difference is that it overrides the `get_value()` method instead of `get_field()`.

While it's a little hacky about how it detects calls in the `get_value()` method, I don't think it's to the point where it would be considered *pathological*. ;-)

```
from __future__ import print_function

from string import Formatter

class CallFormatter(Formatter):
    try:  # deal with Py 2 & 3 difference
        NUMERICS = (int, long)
    except NameError:
        NUMERICS = int

    def get_value(self, key, args, kwargs):
        if key.endswith('()'):  # call?
            return kwargs[key[:-2]]()
        elif isinstance(key, self.NUMERICS):
            return args[key]
        else:
            return kwargs[key]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fmt = CallFormatter()

    def cabbages():
        return 'hello'

    d = dict(name='Fred')

    class Thing(object):
        def __init__(self, value):
            self.attr = value
    th = Thing(42)

    print('d[name]:{d[name]}, th.attr:{th.attr}, '
          'cabbages:{cabbages}'.format(**locals()))
    print(fmt.format('d[name]:{d[name]}, th.attr:{th.attr}, '
                     'cabbages:{cabbages}, cabbages():{cabbages()}', 
                     **locals()))
```

Output:

```
d[name]:Fred, th.attr:42, cabbages:<function cabbages at 0x00BB05F0>
d[name]:Fred, th.attr:42, cabbages:<function cabbages at 0x00BB05F0>, 
                          cabbages():hello
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise there was a 2.7/3 difference, that's annoying. Also I was/am in the unique position where I know everything in the `{}`s is callable, probably most people won't be!

Comment: @Andy: Sorry, I misspoke. Your answer _does_ work, as far as it goes, in Python 2.7 (as does mine).

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the [`get_field`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter.get_field) method of `Formatter` as follows:

```
from string import Formatter
class CallFormatter(Formatter):
    def get_field(self, field_name, *args, **kwargs):
        obj, used_key = Formatter.get_field(self, field_name, *args, **kwargs)
        return obj(), used_key  # obj is the function

fmt = CallFormatter()

In [11]: fmt.format('{cabbages} world', **locals())
Out[11]: 'hello world'
```

Doing something like this comes with a health warning, so I think it's worth pasting the Security Considerations section of [that PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) in full (emphasis added):

> Historically, string formatting has been a **common source of
>       security holes** in web-based applications, particularly if the
>       string formatting system allows arbitrary expressions to be
>       embedded in format strings.
>
> The best way to use string formatting in a way that does not
>       create potential security holes is to **never use format strings
>       that come from an untrusted source**.
>
> Barring that, the next best approach is to **ensure that string
>       formatting has no side effects**.  Because of the open nature of
>       Python, it is **impossible to guarantee** that any non-trivial
>       operation has this property.  What this PEP does is limit the
>       types of expressions in format strings to those in which visible
>       side effects are both rare and strongly discouraged by the
>       culture of Python developers.  So for example, attribute access
>       is allowed because it would be considered pathological to write
>       code where the mere access of an attribute has visible side
>       effects (whether the code has *invisible* side effects - such
>       as creating a cache entry for faster lookup - is irrelevant.)

Comment: The code with `self` in it works for me (or I wouldn't have edited your answer).